# Create a routerLink to a child route that appears in a named <router-outlet>

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I have some named `<router-outlet>` which I can navigate to by url like so: `(outletname:path)`.

I have been able to create a `routerLink` like so:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { outletname : [child.attributes.href] } }]" routerLinkActive="active">{{child.attributes.text}}</a>
```

You can see that I've had to provide `outletname` in `[routerLink]`.  What I would like is to provide the outlet name by a variable.  I'm trying to iterate over a collection of child routes that may use different named `<router-outlet>`.

So is there away to provide the outletname via a variable like so ..?

```
<a [routerLink]="['wordpress/',{ outlets: { OUTLET_NAME_AS_VAR : [child.attributes.href] } }]" routerLinkActive="active">{{child.attributes.text}}</a>
```

Comment: Can't you use {{outlet_name}}, which would be defined in the component?

Comment: @hepifish No, I tried {{ child.attributes.outlet }} - error was  'got interpolation expecting expression'

Comment: Could you please put how your final link should look like? (actual example)

Answer (score 2):

RouterLink can be used for a single path, like this:

```
<a routerLink="wordpress">Link1</a>
```

*(you don't need the square brackets here)*

Or for "composed" paths (what you need), like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['wordpress', var, 'item']">Link2</a>
```

where var is defined in the component. 
Notice two things:

1. var is not in brackets {{}} -> you would get the error you've already mentioned
2. the items are in a list (which you already use, but not correctly). The above mentioned code would become /wordpress/myValue/item
   (ts: public var = 'myValue')

The {} are used for params, so you don't need them, since you only need a normal path.

---

**update**

You can create a json inside your component which would look like this:

```
public outletPaths = {
   outletName: 'value1'
};
```

and you can include it like

```
<a [routerLink]="['wordpress/', {outlets: outletPaths}]"> Go to page </a>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.  You're not using named outlets, this is just a normal router link.

Comment: True, I've checked it once again.I'll edit the response

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. It works well except that the variable should contain the router name and not only the route